# Почему, когда размер текстуры не является степенью двойки, она отображается размытой?

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Почему когда размер текстуры не является степенью двойки, она отображается размытой? Можно ли это победить?
Вот текстура:

[image]

Вот результат:

[image]

Вот код:

```
glClearColor(_r, _b, _g, 1.0);
glClearDepth(1.0);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, _width, 0, _height);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);               
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

...

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.texture);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

glRotatef((double)angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    switch(flip){
        case EGE_FLIP_NONE:
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x, y + h);
        break;
        case EGE_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x, y + h);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x, y);
        break;
        case EGE_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x, y + h);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
        break;
    }
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Размеры текстуры 640x480px, рисую с таким же размером.

Comment: Используйте антиалиасинг и анизотропную фильтрацию.

Comment: Антиалиасинг я включил, а как включить анизотропную фильтрацию?

Comment: @Danatela: Это не решает проблему, а только уменьшает ее.

Comment: А где же ваш код? По гуще гадать как вы это рисуете? :)

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: @egordorichev: Так а где ты задаешь размер для отрисовки (чему равен `w` и `h`) и какой размер у исходной текстуры?

Comment: 640x480, 640x480

Comment: Что изображено на приложеных картинках, фрагмент? Почему они разного размера?

Comment: Да, фрагмент. Но остальная часть просто черный кусок.

Comment: @egordorichev: Почему они разного размера?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23571/discussion-between-egordorichev-and-krom-stern).

Comment: Это скриншот!!!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему когда размер текстуры не является степенью двойки, она отображается размытой?

Дело в том, что вы используете растровое изображение. При растяжении или сжатии такого изображения, в отличие от векторного, оно будет размываться, поскольку информации в нём ровно столько, сколько можно закодировать в пикселях. Когда размер отображаемой области совпадает с размером текстуры, к ней не применяется никаких преобразований, соответственно картинка отображается "как есть". Однако, такая ситуация в 3D-моделировании встречается крайне редко, если не сказать никогда. И натянуть текстуру на полигоны — ещё полбеды. Практически всегда к картинке будут применяться преобразования.

В приведённом примере имеет смысл заменить линейный фильтр `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST` хотя бы на бикубический и использовать текстуру с достаточно большим разрешением, если у вас задача получить красивую картинку на экране. Если же задача стоит именно в отображении конкретной картинки без преобразования, то придётся подгонять каждую текстуру под поверхность.

Comment: Но ведь я не растягиваю текстуру. Я рисую ее с таким же размером, какой у нее. 640x480

Comment: В таком случае, проблема, возможно, в преобразовании типа `int` во `float`. Если я не ошибаюсь, мантисса числа с плавающей точкой хранится в виде отрицательных степеней двойки, поэтому GL-координатам требуются текстуры размера степени двойки. Решение —  либо брать текстуры более высокого разрешения, либо специально приводить их к такому размеру.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

У вас текстура отмасштабировалась на большую область - вот и мыло.
Про степень двойки я тоже смутно помню читал в "красной" книге, возможно в современных версиях OpenGL это уже не обязательное правило. У меня в проекте была большая текстура "атлас", у которой размеры были как раз степенью двойки, в самом атласе уже были рабочие текстуры произвольного размера.

Comment: Это ошибка в моем коде? Не совсем понял, как править.